# Rails Paperclip custom filepath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so I have this model...

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :asset_file_name, :lesson_id, :attachment

  has_attached_file :attachment,
    :url => "/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension"

  validates_presence_of :asset_file_name
  validates_attachment_presence :attachment
end
```

(also have a model for `Lesson`)

I want to save attachments to `/attachments/:lesson_id/:basename.:extension`.
That is not to the `:id` of the asset but the :lesson_id. When I do this the directory is actually just named `:lesson_id`. Anyone know how to get the actual `lesson_id`? I've also tried `@asset.lesson_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a custom interpolator in paperclip.
This is best done in an initializer or somewhere decoupled from the model

```
Paperclip.interpolates('lesson_id') do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.lesson_id
end
```

After that your `:lesson_id` will be the actual `object.lesson_id`